# Why my self made drop down list doesn't work in IE 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

Code works perfectly in other browsers but not in IE7. Problem in IE7 is that the second level of the list(ul .opt_1) won't show when the first level is selected.
Here's the HTML part:

```
<input type="button" id="topic" value="please select a topic"/>
<div class="c"></div>
<ul id="opt_0">
<li class="opt_0">finance</li>
<ul class="opt_1">
<li>business</li>
<li>stock</li>
<li>company</li>
<li>startup</li>
</ul>
<li class="opt_0">IT</li>
<ul class="opt_1">
<li>internet</li>
<li>code</li>
<li>hardware</li>
</ul>
</ul>
<input type="hidden" name="topic"/>
```

and JS part:

```
$(function(){
$("#topic").click(function(){
    $("#opt_0").slideDown();
})
$(".opt_0").click(function(){
        $(".opt_0").removeClass("selected");
        $(this).addClass("selected");
        $(".opt_1").hide();
        $(this).next(".opt_1").show();
    })
$(".opt_1 li").click(function(){
    $("#opt_0").slideUp();
    $("#topic").val($(".selected").html()+">>"+$(this).html());
    $("input[name=\"topic\"]").val($(".selected").html()+";"+$(this).html());
})
})
```

You can see JS fiddle here:http://jsfiddle.net/lornechang/4BmPb/
How do I make it compatible with IE7? Thanks.

Comment: Do you get any javascript errors on IE7 ?

Comment: @ManseUK I don't have an IE7 on my computer. I run it in an IE6 on another computer and it didn't work.I want to find if it works in the later versions so I tried in my computer on a IE9 with the console selected to IE7 mode(both browser mode and document mode), didn't work either with no errors in the console.

Comment: @Diodeus just <!DOCTYPE html>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your html is not valid. I made the changes required to make it correct in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/4BmPb/1/

```
<input type="button" id="topic" value="please select a topic"/>
<div class="c"></div>
<ul id="opt_0">
    <li class="opt_0">finance</li>
    <li class="opt_1">
        <ul>
            <li>business</li>
            <li>stock</li>
            <li>company</li>
            <li>startup</li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="opt_0">IT</li>
    <li class="opt_1">
        <ul>
            <li>internet</li>
            <li>code</li>
            <li>hardware</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<input type="hidden" name="topic"/>
```

A `ul` element can only contain `li` elements, not other `ul` elements.

As far as why it works in other browsers, other browsers are not as strict as IE is with html structure. I tested this in IE9 which presented the same problem, have not tested in IE7 but I suspect it will work too.